# How do I assert that sys.exit gets raised in pytest

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I want to assert in pytest that if my call fails that sys.exit is called.

```
import requests
import sys

def httpRequest(uri):
    try:
        response = requests.get(uri,verify=False)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        sys.exit(1)
    return response
    

uri = 'http://reallybaduri.com/test'
response = httpRequest(uri)
print(response.text)
```

Testing Code:

```
import api_call
import requests
import pytest

def test_httpRequest():
    uri = 'http://reallybaduri.com/test'
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        api_call.httpRequest(uri)
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.type == SystemExit
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.value.code == 42
```

This gives me a "did not raise" error. How Do I assert that an error is raised?

Answer (score 1):

You should change  your code `assert pytest_wrapped_e.value.code == 1` . You are expecting 1 not 42

Comment: Still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

The test will automatically fail if no exception / exception other than `SystemExit` is raised.

The code only needs to be

```
import api_call
import requests
import pytest

def test_httpRequest():
    uri = 'http://reallybaduri.com/test'
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        api_call.httpRequest(uri)
```

Comment: unfortunately that still gives the same error.

Comment: the test works for me -- your problem lies elsewhere and not with the test itself.

Comment: Where do you think the problem could lie?

Comment: can you update your OP with filenames and the exact error code you're getting / stack trace?